# evaluation of volume of solid obtained by rotating the curve $y=x^2,y=x+2$ about $x$ axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluation of volume of  solid obtained by rotating the regin enclosed by the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=x+2$ about $x$ axis,is

What i try:

[image]

Sokving $y=x^2$ and $y=x+2$. we get $x=-1, x=2$

So volume of solid obtained by rotating about $x$ axis is

Here inner radius $r_{1}=y=x^2$ and $r_{2}=y=x+2$

Volume$(V)=$ Outer -Inner $$\int^{2}_{-1}\pi\bigg(x+2-x^2\bigg)dx$$

Can anyone plesse tell me is my solution is Right. If not then How do i solve it. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of a solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the $Ox$ axis, the lines $x=a$,  $x=b$, $b>a$, and the curve $y=f(x)$ is equal to
$$V=\pi\int\limits_{a}^{b} f^2(x)\,dx.$$
So the volume to be found is
$$
V=V_{outer}-V_{inner}= \pi\int\limits_{-1}^{2} (x+2)^2\,dx-\pi\int\limits_{-1}^{2} x^4\,dx
$$